# How to extract the same element from several URLs and save in file?

Tags: javascript, html, extract

I have a list of many URLs for which I want to extract an specific element that have the same query selector in each URL.

For example, having opened in Chrome the URL "http://www.nationalregisterofhistoricplaces.com/al/autauga/state.html"
and then running this command

```
document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(7) > div.listheader")
```

I get the print of the desired content in Chrome browser console (If I should try javascript scripts in another tool, please let me know which one)

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying  and I would like extract div element from URL_1 and save it to out.html, then extract div from URL_2 up to URL_N and append below previous div and so on.

I've tried the following code so far, but it opens only the first URL in a new tab and is not printed its div.

```
var urls = [
"http://www.nationalregisterofhistoricplaces.com/al/autauga/state.html",
"http://www.nationalregisterofhistoricplaces.com/al/barbour/state.html",
"http://www.nationalregisterofhistoricplaces.com/ca/fresno/state.html"
];

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    window.open(urls[i])
    document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(7) > div.listheader")
};
```

My goal is to merge the div of each URL and save them in out.html that would look something like this:

```
<!-- div from URL_1 -->

<div class="listheader">
<img src="/nr-images/flag.gif" width="33" height="28">
<div class="listname">Bell House                                                                                                              
<span class="added">(added 1999 -  - #99000150)</span>
</div>
<div class="listaka">Also known as Biggs House</div>
<div class="listaddress">550 Upper Kingston Rd.                                                                                                  , Prattville
</div>
</div>

<!-- div from URL_2 -->

<div class="listheader">
<img src="/nr-images/flag.gif" width="33" height="28">
<div class="listname">Bray-Barron House                                                                                                       
<span class="added">(added 1971 -  - #71000093)</span>
</div>
<div class="listaddress">N. Eufaula Ave.                                                                                                         , Eufaula
</div>
</div>

<!-- div from URL_3 -->

<div class="listheader">
<img src="/nr-images/flag.gif" width="33" height="28">
<div class="listname">Bank of Italy                                                                                                           
<span class="added">(added 1982 -  - #82000963)</span>
</div>
<div class="listaka">Also known as Bank of America on Fulton Mall</div>
<div class="listaddress">1015 Fulton Mall                                                                                                        , Fresno
</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Below is what I get running the solution provided by @Thomas. I see 3 iframes but when expand them, are empty.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just thought of another way. Because all the URLs are on the same domain, you can actually open them all in iframes, and you're allowed to access each iframe's contents from within your script. Here's how that would look:

```
for (const url of urls) {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.src = url
    iframe.onload = () => {
        console.log(iframe.contentDocument.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(7) > div.listheader"))
    }
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```

Note that the `onload` callback is asynchronous, so you'll get the output in arbitrary order. Also, there's no error handling (attach a callback to `onerror` for that).

If you have a large number of URLs to crawl, you might not want to do them all at the same time like this, because each iframe is like a separate browser tab and takes considerable resources. So you could do it in batches, or only start the next one when the previous one has finished.

Comment: Thanks so much.Thomas for your approach. I'll try to make my tests.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried your solution on Mozilla console. I see an element and when I select to see it in "inspector", I see the 3 iframes, but inside them are empty. You can see the image below my update in original question.

Comment: Are you on a page on this domain when you run the code?

Comment: I had first url active on browser, then I sent F12 to open console, I sent your code and I get the empty iframes. How should I run it?

Answer (score 0):

In the browser console, you're going to have a bad time, because all JavaScript that you write there will run in the context of the current page. As soon as you open a new page, you lose that.

You could do this with NodeJS, which is a standalone JavaScript engine that runs outside the browser. You'll need to write code to fetch the HTML, and a library to parse and query it.

Another approach might be NW.js, which is like a browser but without the sandboxing.

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for your answer. Then after installing NodeJS and run my script as shown in question would work? at least to print in current window the elements I like to extract. If not, may you help me showing how would change the script to run it in NodeJS please.

Comment: It can be done in the browser console but it is a bit of a mess, I have done something similar for a quick dirty hack I needed once.
`Puppeteer` (headless Chrome node.js API) would also be a viable option to scrape the pages if OP wants to do it in javascript.

Comment: @GerCas To do this in NodeJS you will need significant changes because none of the browser APIs are available. And in any case you will have to move away from the browser console and write your code in `.js` files. It's more than would fit into a comment.

Comment: Ok, I undertand. Thank Thomas

Comment: @JimNilsson Maybe to do in browser is there a way to no open each URL, but store the content I want to extract in a variable appending each new elements and print at the end?